# Haskell recursively adding data elements to matrix from string matrix with indiсes

Tags: haskell, recursion, matrix, nested-lists

Please jump to edit:

I have to deal with a problem in my homework, maybe I am completely wrong on that one but I'm new to functional programming.

I have a 5x5 Matrix with Strings in it, I want to read them out, transform them to a data element and applying it to a new matrix.

I am using a recursive approach because I want to add the position of the String into the Data element!

here is what I tried:

```
cycleMatrix :: Int -> Int -> [[String]] -> [[Data]]
cycleMatrix 0 0 matrix = (strToData 0 0 (matrix !! 0) !! 0))
cycleMatrix n 0 matrix = (cycleMatrix (n - 1) 0 matrix):(strToData n 5 ((matrix !! n) !! 5))
cycleMatrix n m matrix = (cycleMatrix n (m - 1) matrix):(strToData n n ((matrix !! n) !! m))
```

with `strToData` I am geting the string from the matrix and passing the x and y returning a Data Object (thats working)

At the moment I am just trying to add every element to an Array but I really want to start a new list every time I am getting to zero on `m` (after `cycleMatrix n 0 matrix`)

My questions are: Is this the way to go and how do I append this element in a correct way?

Edit: Okay I finally got it to work by splitting the functions(thx to Rudi for telling me not to do everything at once)

But my questions still stands. I now have 8 lists full with Data elements
I can append them all to a List with `[] ++ []`, but is there a way to create a matrix out of the lists like `[] : []` (adding a list as element to a list)?

Comment: Do you want to transform the input matrix at once? And do you have to use recursion, or can you use the built in library?

Comment: there are no restrictions, I just need the matrix with the Data elements and the position with it (I hope that I can solve the homework with this one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tackle this problem by enumerating the inner lists into (x, data) tuples¹, then enumerate this enumeration into (y, [x-lists]). This then is the starting point to convert this into the desired format.

You can load this file in ghci with `:load file.hs`, and play with the different functions there.

¹from your edit I guess that this is what you already did

```hs
example :: [[String]]
example = [
        ["as", "df", "ghj"],
        ["xx", "yy"]
    ]

-- add a position number to each list element. Beware
-- that this starts with 1
enumerate :: [a] -> [(Int, a)]
enumerate = zip [1..]

-- does the enumeration, but does not transform the
-- data into the desired format. I put it here, so that
-- the functionality of the different functions is
-- better to understand.
kindofEnumarate2d :: [[a]] -> [(Int, [(Int, a)])]
kindofEnumarate2d = enumerate . map enumerate

-- convert a row of (y, [(x, value)]) tuples into a
-- [((x,y), value)] list
helper :: (Int, [(Int, a)]) -> [((Int, Int), a)]
helper (y, xs) = [((x, y), s) | (x, s) <- xs]

-- transform each row of the "kind-of" transformed
-- rows into the desired format.
enumerate2d :: [[a]] -> [[((Int, Int), a)]]
enumerate2d = map helper . kindofEnumarate2d
```

Comment: Since this is homework, I think you may be giving away a little too much. :-)

Comment: This is a great answer, I just enumerated it by hand (0-8) I may optimize  my function with your explanations!

Comment: @SimonShine I don't think I give away too much here, since there was already work done. And I didn't found a way to explain how to transform nested lists without writing some code which does it.